# Garage Wiring Route Through Ceiling

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have started drilling holes in order to fish wire down from my attic to the garage.  Unfortunately this house doesn't allow me to have easy routes.  Where I currently have the hole through the floor is an ideal location but this comes out the ceiling relatively close to the Garage arm.

I basically need to know if this is ok or if I must find another location.  I plan on running all of this through conduit in the garage since its finished but I wasn't sure if there was a rule regarding how close conduit can be to other objects.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears the danger-close part is the "wing" on the garage door track diagonal brace.

That wing is essential for strengths/stiffness.  But structurally, that brace doesn't care if the wing sticks out that way, or the other.   I would just flip it over/put it on the other side, so the wing sticks out the other way.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll run NB from the attic into a junction box mounted in the garage then run THHN in the conduit. You're good to go. Just make sure you check the operation of the garage door and opener before mounting any conduit. Make sure you're not blocking any doors.... been there, done that in my much younger years